# Strange result with Debug.WriteLine and string.Join

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2015

this code

```
byte[] frame = BuildMessageFrame(message);
Debug.WriteLine("TX: {0}", string.Join(", ", frame));
```

I would assume that it would give a line like:

```
TX: 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2
```

instead I get:

```
0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2: TX: {0}
```

Why?

PS! I'm using .net 4.5.2 but I couldn't find any tag for this version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using this method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w33ay0x(v=vs.110).aspx which is using `string.Join(", ", frame)` as the category.

Presumably you were expecting behaviour like String.Format, so you'd need to explicitly use that.

Facepalm?

Comment: Seem a bit illogical to me, but... No Facepalm! It's not my code ;-) Thank you very much!